A valid trigonometric identity fails to give a solution for an equation
I am trying to solve the following trigonometric equation:
$\frac{dy}{dx}= \cos x -\sin x ~=~0$
I tried three methods:
Method I:

In line 2, I used the identity: sin x = cos (90-x)
Method II:

In line 2, I used the identity: cos (90+x) = -sin x
In line 3, I used the identity: cos (a+b) = 2 cos (a+b)/2 cos (a-b)/2
Method III:

In line 2, I used the identity: sin (90+x) = cos x
Clearly, method III is not applicable, though a valid identity is used in line 2.
Is it possible to give an explanation for the failure of method III? Please help.

Perhaps you need to consider that the trigonometric equations have multiple solutions

if $\sin x=\sin y$, then you can also have $\pi-x=y$

When doing calculus, angles should be measured in radians, not degrees. The derivative formula are wrong if you measure angles in degrees.

@TymaGaidash Thank you for the link. The answers in that link give great insight into these types of problems.

@ArturoMagidin Thank you. I agree.
